# Find and assign a unique IP address to a device

Tags: c#, ip

I need to assign a unique IP address (local) for a device we will be connecting into our system via. USB.  The actually assigning I will do over RS232 (don't ask!) by telling the device what it's IP is.

I would like to somehow find a usable address relative to the local PC in order to tell the device which to use.  Is there a way of enumerating or finding a usable address in C#?  I don't want to simply use a fixed one in case of possible clashes with other devices.

I've done a search here and there's lots of people wanting to find the current IP, or the IP of an already existing device, but I can't find much about generating a usable, unique one.

Thanks for any assistance you can give me.

Comment: If you know the subnet mask and your own ip, you can [calculate all valid ip addresses](http://www.subnet-calculator.com/). You then could enumerate them until you found a unused address (maybe by pinging the address).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol

> The Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol (DHCP) is a network
>   configuration protocol for hosts on Internet Protocol (IP) networks.
>   Computers that are connected to IP networks must be configured before
>   they can communicate with other hosts. The most essential information
>   needed is an IP address, and a default route and routing prefix. DHCP
>   eliminates the manual task by a network administrator. It also
>   provides a central database of devices that are connected to the
>   network and eliminates duplicate resource assignments. In addition to
>   IP addresses, DHCP also provides other configuration information,
>   particularly the IP addresses of local Domain Name Server (DNS),
>   network boot servers, or other service hosts. DHCP is used for IPv4 as
>   well as IPv6. While both versions serve much the same purpose, the
>   details of the protocol for IPv4 and IPv6 are sufficiently different
>   that they may be considered separate protocols.[1] Hosts that do not
>   use DHCP for address configuration may still use it to obtain other
>   configuration information. Alternatively, IPv6 hosts may use stateless
>   address autoconfiguration. IPv4 hosts may use link-local addressing to
>   achieve limited local connectivity.

Comment: Ok, I'm going with Tians here as he was first to post with DHCP solution.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Assigning static IP addresses (even if you ping them) is a bad idea.
What happens if the IP address you've assigned is to a device that happens to be offline right now?

Use DHCP if you can, and consider prompting the user if you can not retrieve an IP address from DHCP as to what it should be assigned to.

I am not ware of a native C# library for DHCP client's, but using pinvoke will get you what you're after.  Example code (not tested) here, http://www.ianatkinson.net/computing/dhcpcsharp.htm

Answer (score 1):

Ok, not really sophisticated or anything, but why don't you just try to ping the ips, starting by the lowest, and pick the first one which doesn't respond?

Comment: Not a bad idea in itself.  But I was kind-of hoping the OS would somehow know what's available and what isn't.  Perhaps it's too much to hope for...

Comment: That's definately a bad idea, machines might block icmp, and ping wouldn't work.

Comment: Yeah, as I said, not a really sophisticated idea. There could also be some devices with static IP-Adresses which are turned of at the moment and could lead to conflicts when they are turned on.